# Undefined control sequence listings package

Tags: listings, packages, texmaker

I'm working with TexMaker and I can't compile my documents because it apears de problem "Indefined control sequence", with the \usepackage{listings}. How do I fix it?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\topmargin=15pt
\oddsidemargin=60pt
\textwidth=340pt
\textheight=545pt
\footskip=30pt

\usep­a­ck­age{list­ings}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}{Language={C++},caption= "Código en C++para resolver polinomios",frame=single,numbers=left]

 const int N = 10;

double resolver(double[] polinomio, double x) {
   double resultado = polinomio[0];
   double potencia = x;
   for (int i=1; i<N; i++) {
     resultado+=polinomio[i]*potencia;
     potencia = potencia*x;
   }
   return resultado;
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: There is something between `\usep­a` and `ck­age{list­ings}`. See syntax highlighting fails?

Comment: I rewritted again the package (although it wasn't anything between "\usepa and ckage") and added the changes of Thomas F. Sturm and it works well right now.

Answer (score 2):

There were several problems:

- Some source code character problem in your `\usepackage` text.
- The caption text was delimited by `"`
- You used a `]` instead of a `}` to close the parameter list of `lstlisting`.

The following works:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\topmargin=15pt
\oddsidemargin=60pt
\textwidth=340pt
\textheight=545pt
\footskip=30pt

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}{Language={C++},caption={Código en C++para resolver polinomios},frame=single,numbers=left}

 const int N = 10;

double resolver(double[] polinomio, double x) {
   double resultado = polinomio[0];
   double potencia = x;
   for (int i=1; i<N; i++) {
     resultado+=polinomio[i]*potencia;
     potencia = potencia*x;
   }
   return resultado;
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It is [U+C2AD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c2ad/index.htm), an invalid unicode character. (i.e. fonts do not need to display it.)

Comment: @Symbol1 Yes, I guess the editor of the OP has hidden it. Luckily, my editor does not :-)

Comment: My editor does hide it :'( What editor are you using?

Comment: @Symbol1 I am using [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/).

Comment: @Symbol1 I've just checked that TeXworks does not show it directly, but one can see a highlight problem.